# SpriteKit Swift: How to make a sprite jump in place when tapped?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

So Ive been working on a game and have a little sprite that is currently running in place. I need to make him jump up whenever the user taps the screen to dodge obstacles. I also need him to return to his starting point on the ground after he jumps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using physics is overkill for a game like this. Not even the 2D Mario games use physics so I doubt you will need it.

As a very simple implementation you can use a sequence of `SKAction`s.

```
// move up 20
let jumpUpAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 20, duration: 0.2)
// move down 20
let jumpDownAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -20, duration: 0.2)
// sequence of move yup then down
let jumpSequence = SKAction.sequence([jumpUpAction, jumpDownAction])

// make player run sequence
player.run(jumpSequence)
```

That should work. I may have mistyped something in the browser though.

You can tweak this to make the jump look more natural. Maybe add a few more steps to the jump process to change the speed of the rise/fall over time to make it look like he's accelerating. etc...

Comment: Will try this out, thanks a ton!! Also, would I put this in a separate function or didMoveToView or touchesBegan?

Comment: @RaeTucker Well this is a single jump so you will need to run this every time you want the character to jump. So I suggest putting it in a function that is called from your touches began function.

Comment: Thank you, but whenever I run it, my sprite doesn't budge.

Comment: It keeps saying "use of unresolved identifier: player" when I have player set up as the name of my sprite: let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed "koala_walk01")

Comment: You need to replace player with whatever you have called your actual player Sprite variable.

Comment: Would I replace it with a property that i set at the top of GameScene? Also, "player" is what I've been calling my sprite.

Answer (score 12):

You can try something like this!

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var player: SKSpriteNode?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
        jump()
    }

    func jump() {
        player?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player_jumping")
        player?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 500))
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
        player?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player_standing")
    }

}
```

On the player's attribute inspector window make sure you select 'Dynamic' and 'Affected By Gravity' options only, otherwise it will not fall back to the ground after the jump.. :)

I don't think physics would be overkill for a simple game as someone said in the previous answer... It's not a big deal for an iPhone or iPad hardware, they have a crazy computing power.

[image]

Comment: Hi, that's what I needed, thank you. How to test the jump is on going? I would avoid to apply a new impulse while the guy is in the air. The first think it comes up in my mind is to test collision among the guy and the ground. If colliding then apply the impulse, else not. Is it the right approach?